# Youtube has no voice but the music continues just fine?

Tags: windows-xp, audio, codec

PC CONFIG:

> gigabyte EP45C UD3R with the realtek
>   HD onboard
>
> 4gb dual channel
>
> Qcore 2.83ghz

When i watch to videos on youtube now the voice some times is in static and some times so low that you can hear it while the sound continues just fine...

For example if can hear to things like guitar or a train etc but the voice of whoever is speaking is gone or very low or pure static when watching the videos.

I know some videos have a really great quality and some are HD 1080p so this was something not expected to happen.

I can aswell play videos on my WMP11 just fine i have ccc-p installed also tried k-lite, both on the latest stable avaiable.

I havent tried anything else related to flash but something is either wrong with my drivers or youtube.

I have installed the latest drivers to make sure they are up-to-date but this didnt help either.

---

What i have tried so far:

- removed the audio drivers and re-installed
- remove any codec pack i had and re-installed k-lite, test, didnt worked
- remove any codec pack i had and re-installed cccp, test, didnt worked
- checked the control panel sound configurations, tried chaging to phone stereo, to 5.1 which is what my headphone is.
- checked the realtek manager, tried changing the sound channels from 2CH to 6CH to reflect my headphone, didnt work.
- rebooted after every change of the above tries.
- tried chrome, firefox and internet explorer with the same results didnt w

Comment: Does your sound card driver have a control panel with a vocal removal or karaoke setting? If so, make sure it's turned off.

Comment: could you possible point me to a image or where that is located ? i am not sure but i belive it doesnt ... Ive searched and look for lots of things around trying to fix it and didnt saw anything related to karaoke or voice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem Solved!**

In the end the culprit was the headphone, it is a zalman 5.1 but something was wrong with the inside cables perhaps it was cut or something and in 5.1 it was not producing sound while the 2.0 was doing just fine.

I figured that out after trying another zalman 5.1 I had laying around ... it was beat up but still working properly, also tried a home theater 5.1 to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Does your sound card driver have a control panel with a vocal removal or karaoke setting? If so, make sure it's turned off.

It might look like this:

[image]

(The [manual for your motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2953&dl=#manual) shows a very similar audio manager program on page 103, although it doesn't mention the Sound Effect tab in detail.)

Comment: +1 for the hard work. yes they were never on now i know what you were talking about karaoke was always 0 and i never turned on the equalizer of realtek manager.

Answer (score -1):

Your left and right channel were probably in phase. If a voice (or any sound) is panned dead center, the sound of left and right cancel each other out