# What sound card is better and what should i take into consideration to consider it?

Tags: sound-card, windows-xp, comparison

I have a [Sound Blaster Live ! 24-bit 7.1](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16829102003&cm_re=24-bit-_-29-102-003-_-Product) and a [onboard sound card Realtek ALC889A codec High Definition Audio 2/4/5.1/7.1-channel that comes on my gigabyte motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2953&dl=1#sp).

What should i take into consideration to compare both ?
Which one would you consider better ?

I have both a home theather 5.1 and a head phone 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no feasible difference. The Audigy SE is stripped down model, with a less expensive CA-0106 audio-controller in place of the EMU10k2 in standard Audigy cards.

> With the CA-0106, the SE/Value are limited to **software-based** EAX 3.0 (upgraded to software-based EAX 4.0 with a driver update), **no advanced resolution DVD-Audio Playback**, and **no Dolby Digital 5.1 or Dolby Digital EX 6.1 playback**.

So with such card you just using your PCI-slot ) and also you will get all the problems and bugs with Creative drivers in Vista or Win7. Realtek drivers are simpler and in many cases trouble-free.

Comment: +1 I see, but the main reason i am thinking about switch is the current problem i am having with the realtek http://superuser.com/questions/200856/youtube-has-no-voice-but-the-music-continues-just-fine so i was wondering how compareable the 2 are or if i should buy something else.

Comment: If you want to get from new soundcard something more than just NEW soundcard I recommend to find low-cost xfi card like XTremeMusic or XTremeGamer. They have EMU20k1 on board. Don't buy XTremeAudio - it is just equal to Audigy SE.

Answer (score 0):

The Sound Blaster Audigy card you have will be better than the onboard sound chip as it has it's own sound processor and generally speaking, decent add-on sound cards have better sample rate and Signal to Noise Ratio than on-board chips.

Also, the Audigy card supports EAX® ADVANCED HD™ 3.0 which will provide better surround effects (i.e. you will hear objects/people positioned better in the surround sound field) in things such as games , the on-board Realtek chip does not support this.

Comment: +1 thanks,where did u find out about "Signal to Noise Ratio" i didnt saw anything on the specs of either to compare.

Comment: The Realtek chip spec's are here: http://www.realtek.com.tw/products/productsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=28&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=173 and it lists a SNR of 108db. Not sure how accurate that is though in real usage. The Creative card is around 100db SNR I think from memory. I would use the Creative card over the onboard due to the EAX Advanced HD support, it generally provides better sound detail than the on-board chip sound effects.